# Configure CLI interpreter for PhpStorm on Mac

Tags: php, phpstorm, configure

I have installed PHP from brew and it works just fine in VSCode, but in PhpStorm I am not able to configure the interpreter in order to debug my PHP code.
In the configuration file, it says "PHP not installed" with a red icon, and the executable path is empty.

I am trying to debug just code, not a web page, so there is no need of Apache Server or other for now.

When executing `php -v` on terminal, I get:

```
PHP 8.0.17 (cli) (built: Apr  5 2022 22:43:04) ( NTS ) Copyright (c)
The PHP Group Zend Engine v4.0.17, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.17, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

which tells me that this installed correctly.

Comment: 1) So what do you get in PhpStorm? Show the screenshots. Do you see a different PHP version in the IDE? Or you get an error? or wrong config etc? 2) Note that you do not need a PHP Interpreter configured in PhpStorm if you are debugging a web page that is served by your Apache/nginx etc. But it is needed for debugging local CLI scripts and running other PHP based tools (like running PHPUnit tests in the IDE etc).

Comment: @LazyOne just one version of PHP 8.0.17, updated the question to be clearer.

Comment: *"In the configuration file, it says "PHP not installed" with a red icon, and the executable path is empty."* So .. have you tied to specify the path to PHP executable there? You need to point it to the executable. I'm not sure if just having `php` there will be enough. Check what you get when running `which php` (or maybe it's `where php`, sorry, not a Mac user) in your OS terminal and use that path.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per [PhpStorm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-local-interpreter.html) you have to point to PHP executable there (which means: provide the full path). Just having `php` may not be enough.

1. Open your OS terminal and type `which php` (or it could be `where php`; this depends on the OS used). It will show the full path to the executable that gets executed when you run `php` in that terminal.

   [image: path]

   If you have more than one PHP version installed and want to use non-default PHP installation/version then use the path for that specific version.
2. Copy that full path from there (if there are more than one path then use the top most or the most desired one) and use it in the "PHP executable" field of the PHP Interpreters screen in PhpStorm.

   [image: PhpStorm config]